# What flowering plants will do well in Southern California outside in pots all year round?

Tags: flowers

I live in Pasadena, CA, which is USDA hardiness zone 10a, I believe.

I'd like to add some color to my outdoor space via flowering plants in pots. I'm looking for flowers with vibrant colors that will do well here with minimal care, and which will never be brought inside.